# listen the localhost with two different ports

Tags: javascript, tcp

How to listen the localhost with two different ports at the same time.

I have two local servers(two win32 exe's) which are called in a single script as shown below:

server1:exe 1

```
xmr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmr.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:5007/?command=init&comport=com2", true);
```

server 2:exe 2

```
 xmr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmr.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:5009/?command=init&comport=com5&", true);
```

In Script when i start the first server followed by the second ,the first one is initialised ,while the second doesnt connect to the port resulting  in the following error & viceversa  :

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:5009/?command=init&comport=com5& net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

How to handle such situation.

PS: This is my first Tcp/IP programming experience . Sorry  for the poor english .
Any explanation with sample code is much appreciable .

Comment: Would it be easier for you to make a backend service and run each server in a seperate thread or do you **want** to run it in javascript only.

Comment: Right now it is in testing phase .since am a newbie mostly deal  with javascript .

Comment: I recommend using a webapi to pass the data from javascript to the backend, be it java, c# etc, and run you create your tcp connections from the backend as you have access to threads. Also If this javascript is on a page, and it changes, the servers will be out of scope and therefore will be killed. If they are created in the backend they wont be

Answer (score 0):

Please configure ports in IIS.

Refer below steps:
-   IIS->Website->Bindings -> add require ports under HTTP[image]

Refer attached screen shot.